# how to setup my wifi router for wifi advertising

Tags: wireless-networking

came across a site where your name was mentioned because of feedback on WiFi advertising.
I would like to know from someone or whoever can help.
You all heard of sifinor Bluetooth advertising and I am interested in both,but beacons is difficult because I do not know coding.
Then tell me is a WiFi router that I use at home for the internet what they are taking about.Can it be used so that it push a advertisement to everyone who walks past and they will he it on their phone if their wifi is on.I want to know how I can setup my WiFi router for this.Only thing is I have a spare WiFi router that I can used but also a WiFi router that is connected to the internet and that I am using.
Please let me know who can help.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It would be a huge security problem if you could push ads to random passers-by via Wi-Fi.

If you provide a public Wi-Fi network and they *choose* to join it, you can redirect any insecure HTTP requests to a web page, and that page could have an ad. This is known as "captive portal". Not all Wi-Fi APs support it, although some that don't support it can be flashed with aftermarket firmware distros like OpenWrt, DD-WRT, Tomato, etc. that may include captive portal functionality.

Product recommendations don't fit the SuperUser format very well, so you'll have to find a captive portal AP on your own.